# Why is warning log not being passed through my custom formatter?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I'm trying to have every log message my python application produces formatted with my custom formatter. The issue is that my application is not logging everything with my customer formatter, i.e. this RunTimeWarning:

`__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide`

whereas I am expecting something like - i.e. formatted with jsonlogger:

`{"name": "root", "funcName": "<module>", "level": null, "lineno": 1, "threadName": "MainThread", "message": "RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide"}`

Does anyone have any advice as to how to fix? I assumed assigning root logger to use `json_handler` would be enough. To reproduce, here is the code!

```
import logging
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pythonjsonlogger import jsonlogger
from logging import getLogger, config


log_level = os.environ.get("LOG_LEVEL", "INFO")
log_format = "%(name) %(funcName) %(level) %(lineno) %(threadName) %(message)"

config.dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'formatters': {'json': {
        '()': jsonlogger.JsonFormatter,
        'format': log_format,
    }},
    'handlers': {
        'json_handler': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'json',
            'level': log_level,
            'stream': sys.stdout
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handler': ['json_handler'],
            'level': log_level,
            'propagate': False
        },
       
    },
    'root': {
        'level': log_level,
        'handlers': ['json_handler'],
    },
    'disable_existing_loggers': True
})

logging.info("test") # this formats

series_raw = pd.Series([0, float('nan'), 1,4,6,-1], [0,1,2,3,4,5])

x = series_raw.values

values = np.where(np.logical_or(x == 0, np.isnan(x)), np.nan, 10 /x) # warning from here does not
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to re-route `py.warnings` to standard logger with `logging.captureWarnings(capture=True)`  for anyone with same issue.